# App won't load Preference Page while setting up on Pixel device/s only

Tags: android, flutter, pixel

We have an app on beta testing (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dodobits.app). The app works perfectly on almost all device models except pixel 6 and 7. One of my friends installed app and while greeted with the initial setup screen their preference page is blank and cannot move forward. (Preference page is where they select categories of news they like to read. The app is a news app for Indian market).

Since the doesn't crash or we cannot replicate on our test devices we have no idea how to proceed further. We don't have pixel 6 or 7 devices to test at our end, but testing on android studio pixel 6 and 6 pro emulators don't show any issue. The app works perfectly fine

Any help will be greatly appreciated in this matter.

1. Tried on multiple test devices except pixel 6 and 7
2. Used an emulator to replicate the issue and the app works fine on emulator
3. Tried to check if server is reachable for users device and it is reachable.
4. No issues or crashes reported on playstore.
   I am really out of options here..

App is developed using flutter

Comment: Do you use Crashlytics or any other tool? Any exceptions/errors/crash logs?